# Daphne + Supervisor inside Docker Container can't access my application

Tags: nginx, supervisord, daphne

I'm trying to scale my Django app that uses Daphne server inside Docker container with Supervisor because Daphne has no workers. I read on the internet that it should be done that way but I didn't find any explanation of concept and the documentation is very obscure.

I managed to run it all inside container, logs are okay. I firstly run my app without supervisord with multiple containers and it worked fine. That is, I hosted multiple instance of same app in multiple containers because of redundancy. Then I read that I could run multiple processes of my app using supervisor inside container.  So I managed to run app with supervisord and daphne inside container, I get logs that app is running, but I can't access it from my browser as I could when I had only one Daphne process per container without supervisord.

UPDATE:
I can even curl my application inside of container when I use `curl localhost:8000`, but I can't curl it by container's IP address nor inside, nor outside of the container. That means that it's not visible outside of container despite container's port being exposed in docker-compose file.

I'm getting

```
502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.18.0
```

My supervisord config file looks like this:

```
[supervisord]
    nodaemon=true
    [supervisorctl]
    
    [fcgi-program:asgi]
    User=root

    # TCP socket used by Nginx backend upstream
    socket=tcp://localhost:8000

    # Directory where your site's project files are located
    directory=/app
    
    # Each process needs to have a separate socket file, so we use process_num
    # Make sure to update "mysite.asgi" to match your project name
    command= /usr/local/bin/daphne -u /run/daphne/daphne%(process_num)d.sock --endpoint fd:fileno=0     --access-log - --proxy-headers WBT.asgi:application

    # Number of processes to startup, roughly the number of CPUs you have
    numprocs=4
    
    # Give each process a unique name so they can be told apart
    process_name=asgi%(process_num)d
    
    # Automatically start and recover processes
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true

    # Choose where you want your log to go
    stdout_logfile=/home/appuser/supervisor_log.log
    redirect_stderr=true
```

I can't see why NGINX throws 502 error.
This configuration worked until I introduced supervisor.
My Nginx is also inside its own docker container.

```
upstream django_daphne{
    
    hash $remote_addr consistent;
    
    server django_daphne_1:8000;
    server django_daphne_2:8000;
    server django_daphne_3:8000;
}

server {
    
    server_name xxx.yyy.zzz.khmm;
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 64M;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django_daphne;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        #Websocket support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
    
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://api_app:8888;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you end up putting your supervisor package? Did you put it in the same container as daphne, the same container as nginx, or its own separate container entirely?

Comment: @Timothyjames67 I put it in the same container as Daphne beecause that way it can access Daphne process.

Comment: @Timothyjames67 Nginx is in its own container and it redirects requests to other containers. It has nothing to do with supervisor and Daphne.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay! I found out what is a problem.
Instead of

```
socket=tcp://localhost:8000
```

it has to be

```
socket=tcp://0.0.0.0:8000
```

so that it can be accessed outside of the container.